# Add array of lines between two lines

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, insert

I have a configuration file with text similar as below:

```
 <Directory />
     Options -Indexes
 </Directory>
```

Need to replace this as below using powershell.

```
 <Directory />
     AllowOverride none
     Require all denied
 </Directory>
```

I used the code as below:

```
 $HttpPath = "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\my_domain\config\fmwconfig\components\OHS\ohs1\httpd.conf"
 $Lines = @("AllowOverride none", "", "Require all denied")
 $Pattern = '(?s)(?<=<Directory />\r?\n).*?(?=</Directory>)'
 $NewLine = "{0}{1}" -f "$Lines",[Environment]::NewLine
  (Get-Content $HttpPath -raw) -replace $Pattern,$NewLine | Set-Content $HttpPath
```

But this is not placing the array elements on separate lines, it combining the elements as foloows-

```
 <Directory />
    AllowOverride none  Require all denied
 </Directory>
```

Need solution to place those lines on separate lines.

Comment: Are you sure that your source files are right?  That looks like XML, but having a self-terminated node followed by a node terminator is invalid syntax.

Comment: Here <Directory /> is not a self-terminating tag. Here "/" is the directory path and this can e different path also. </Directory> is the closing tag for <Directory />

Comment: Incorrect.  In XML, that would require some kind of attribute specifier like: `<Directory Path="/">`

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley I'm guessing this is some sort of propriety file format. That's definitely not valid XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining the array elements instead:

```bsh
$HttpPath = "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\my_domain\config\fmwconfig\components\OHS\ohs1\httpd.conf"
$Lines = @("AllowOverride none", "", "Require all denied")
$Pattern = '(?s)(?<=<Directory />\r?\n).*?(?=</Directory>)'
$NewLine = [string]::Join([Environment]::NewLine,$Lines)+[Environment]::NewLine
(Get-Content $HttpPath -raw) -replace $Pattern,$NewLine | Set-Content $HttpPath
```

`[string]::Join` takes an array of strings and "stitches" them together using the passed character og string.

You code only inserts the newline after all the elements.

Comment: Closing-tag getting upwards together with the line. Need to place closing-tag below on the separate line.